# Avoid /usr/bin/xauth: error in locking authority file /home/user/.Xauthority

Tags: ssh, login, locking

In batch scripts I often log in to the same system through ssh multiple times. E.g.

```
seq 1000 | parallel -j0 -S server echo
```

This triggers a race condition giving the error:

```
/usr/bin/xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/user/.Xauthority
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to **not** forward X when you log in with ssh. You shouldn't really need it, do you?

If you do not want to take out `ForwardX11 true` from your `~/.ssh/config` (I am guessing that's where it got set), you can try adding `-x` to the command line.

```
seq 1000 | parallel -j0 -S server -x echo
```

Answer (score 4):

You could disable X-forwarding in your SSH config for this server.

For instance in your `$HOME/.ssh/config` you could have

```
  Host server
             ForwardX11 no
```